# Finding nested dynamically generated elements with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with Selenium and the Chrome Driver, But I haven't been able to find an element by ID. However, this element is visible in the web inspector of the browser. I think this is because the element is dynamically generated (all the time I see the same URL in the Browser Url Bar, but content changes dynamically.

The way to solve it is to properly undersand driver waits. The first page is the login page which I can get past by succesfully:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
delay = 5

username = driver.find_element_by_name('Username')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('Password')
username.send_keys('my_username')
password.send_keys('my_password')
login = driver.find_element_by_id('login_button')
login.click()
```

After this step I can succesfully find the element called say, button_a, after I click on this, the page generates a new button say, button_b, for which I use a wait for presence command.

```
button_a = driver.find_element_by_id('button_a')
button_a.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        driver.find_element_by_id('button_b')))
```

However this throws the classic exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:     Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"button_b"}
```

It seems that the driver is keeping a reference to the old DOM and doesn't keep track of new elements added to the DOM, the page is not reloaded after the click on button_a but I just get the classic Spin Wheel where the client is dynamically generating new content. At this point I can clearly see that the button_b id exists by right clicking on the browser and then inspect.

Is this possible to solve with Selenium?

Excuse me I'm just a total noob in web browser automation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are going wrong, you are going to find element then use wait for WebElement. You should try using By locator instead as below :-

```
button_a = driver.find_element_by_id('button_a')
button_a.click()
button_b = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'button_b')))
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the driver is keeping a reference to the old DOM and
>   doesn't keep track of new elements added to the DOM, the page is not
>   reloaded after the click on button_a but I just get the classic Spin
>   Wheel where the client is dynamically generating new content.
>   Actually Selenium detects any changes made to the DOM made by page reload, AJAX calls, Javascript execution, etc. 
>   So, to put this to test, if you have let's say your `button_a` and try the following:

```
buttonA = driver.find_element_by_id("button_a")
//Ajax call here
buttonA.click()
```

you will get a `StaleElementReferenceException` error(element is no longer attached to DOM) meaning that any bindings made by Selenium to that element are lost.

Now, to overcome the issue that you have, using your example, you could go with:

```
//get the first element, button_a and click it
//going by your example this means you have only one element containing `button`
//in the `id`
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'button')]").click()
//now, as you say, you will have 2 elements containing `button` in the `id`
//so get all the elements and click on the last one
buttonB = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'button')]")
buttonB[len(buttonB)-1].click()
```

As a note, I apologize for any syntax errors if any, as I'm not a pythonist.